# How to apply rounded border radius in opposite direction on hover on menu item in menubar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to apply rounded border radius in opposite direction on hover on menu item in menubar

I want this effect on menu item hover

[image]

Currently my menubar looks like this

[image]

This is my css code

```
sidebar-menu .dropdown-toggle:hover, .sidebar-menu .show>.dropdown-toggle {
background: #f8f9fa;
color: #2daab8;
border-top-left-radius: 50px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 70px;
border-top-right-radius: 70px;
width: 250px;
```

}

HTML Code:

```
<div class="left-side-bar lftsideBar">
<div class="brand-logo">
  <a href="{% url 'home' %}">
    <img src="{% static 'website/vendors/images/Rectangle_33.png' %}" alt="" />
  </a>
</div>
<div class="close-sidebar" data-toggle="left-sidebar-close">
  <i class="ion-close-round"></i>
</div>

<div class="menu-block customscroll">
  <div class="sidebar-menu">
    <ul id="accordion-menu menucls" style="margin-left: 25px !important;margin-bottom:250px;">
      <li>
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="dropdown-toggle no-arrow">
          <span class="micon dw  dw-house-1"></span><span class="mtext">Home</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle no-arrow">
          <span class="micon dw dw-add-user"></span><span class="mtext">Client</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle no-arrow">
          <span class="micon dw dw-add-user"></span><span class="mtext">Medical</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle no-arrow">
          <span class="micon dw dw-add-user"></span><span class="mtext">Social</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle no-arrow">
          <span class="micon dw dw-add-user"></span><span class="mtext">Transportation</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle no-arrow">
          <span class="micon dw dw-add-user"></span><span class="mtext">Activity</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle no-arrow">
          <span class="micon dw dw-add-user"></span><span class="mtext">Food</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle no-arrow">
          <span class="micon dw dw-add-user"></span><span class="mtext">Reports</span>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you please suggest me to what css make changes so I can make exactly same design as per screenshot-1 on each and every item of menubar?

Comment: Could you please include the HTML so we have a base to work with?

Comment: I have added code here.

Comment: Unfortunately this code does not reproduce what you show in your image. We need to be able to reproduce it...

Comment: Does CSS clip path help?

Comment: I wanted to suggest clip path or mask, but they aren't widely available. Firefox only allows masks using SVG, so we'd need to create an inline svg and blah blah... But yeh I guess this would work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[source code from there](https://www.cssscript.com/sidebar-menu-curved-outside/)

```js
const initNavBar = () => {
  const menusEl = document.querySelectorAll('.side-bar ul li')
  menusEl.forEach(menu => menu.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    const menuActiveEl = document.querySelector('.side-bar ul li.active')
    menuActiveEl.classList.remove('active')
    menu.classList.add('active')
  }))
}
initNavBar()
```

```css
:root {
  --color-primary: #1380b8;
  --color-secondary: #33ace3;
}
aside.side-bar-wrap {
  --radius-size: 25px;
  height: 98vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 1vh;
  left: 1vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border-radius: var(--radius-size);
  padding-right: 2px;
}
aside.side-bar-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}
aside.side-bar-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: transparent;
}
aside.side-bar-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: var(--radius-size);
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
}
nav.side-bar {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: var(--radius-size) solid var(--color-secondary);
  border-right: var(--radius-size) solid var(--color-primary);
  border-radius: var(--radius-size);
}
nav.side-bar .logo-area {
  --curve-size: calc(2 * var(--radius-size));
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: var(--curve-size);
  background-color: var(--color-secondary);
  border-radius: 0 var(--radius-size) var(--radius-size) 0;
  box-shadow: var(--radius-size) 0 var(--color-secondary);
}
nav.side-bar .logo-area::after {
  content: '';
  width: var(--curve-size);
  height: var(--curve-size);
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(-1 * var(--curve-size));
  left: 0;
  box-shadow:  calc(-1 * var(--curve-size) * 0.5)  calc(-1 * var(--curve-size) * 0.5) var(--color-secondary);
}
nav.side-bar .logo-area img {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 75%;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
aside.side-bar-wrap:hover nav.side-bar .logo-area img.min {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
nav.side-bar .logo-area img.max {
  max-width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
aside.side-bar-wrap:hover nav.side-bar .logo-area img.max {
  max-width: 90%;
  opacity: 1;
}
nav.side-bar ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: calc(2 * var(--radius-size)) 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
nav.side-bar ul li {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px var(--radius-size);
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: var(--radius-size);
  margin-bottom: var(--radius-size);
  z-index: 1;
}
nav.side-bar ul li:not(.active) {
  z-index: 2;
}
nav.side-bar ul li:not(.active):hover {
  backdrop-filter: brightness(0.85);
}
nav.side-bar ul li.active {
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--color-secondary);
  border-radius: 0 var(--radius-size) var(--radius-size) 0;
}
nav.side-bar ul li.active::before,
nav.side-bar ul li.active::after {
  --curve-size: calc(2 * var(--radius-size));
  content: '';
  width: var(--curve-size);
  height: var(--curve-size);
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
nav.side-bar ul li.active::before {
  top: calc(-1 * var(--curve-size));
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: calc(-1 * var(--curve-size) * 0.5) calc(var(--curve-size) * 0.5) var(--color-secondary);
}
nav.side-bar ul li.active::after {
  bottom: calc(-1 * var(--curve-size));
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: calc(-1 * var(--curve-size) * 0.5) calc(-1 * var(--curve-size) * 0.5) var(--color-secondary);
}
nav.side-bar ul li a{
  color: white;
  font-size: 16pt;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 0;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 1s;
}
aside:hover nav.side-bar ul li a{
  gap: 10px;
}
nav.side-bar ul li a span {
  display: flex;
  transition: 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.58, 0.57, 1);
}
nav.side-bar ul li a span.icon {
  font-size: 24pt;
}
nav.side-bar ul li a span.title {
  max-width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
aside:hover nav.side-bar ul li a span.title {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 10rem;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<aside class="side-bar-wrap">
  <nav class="side-bar">
    <div class="logo-area">  
      <img class="min" src="images/min-logo.png" alt="logo">
      <img class="max" src="images/max-logo.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="title">Home</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="title">News</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="title">Jobs</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="title">Contact</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="title">About</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need imagination to be able to create the inverted radius. We could use a circle and use it to mask a square, but CSS mask is not very well supported still. But we can extend on this strategy and use borders to fill the part of a square not occupied by the circle.

In my example below, I've used a holder with `overflow:hidden` to hide any overflowing border. The size of the holder also determines the size of the final curve since the div inside spans to 100%. Instead of using a full circle, I've used just the 1/4 of it that was needed by rounding just the interesting corner to 100%. The color of the border determines the color of the curve.

```css
.holder{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.holder div{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   border-bottom-right-radius:100%;
   border:99999px solid black;
   border-left:none;
   border-top:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Now, armed with that knowledge, you can easily do the same for the bottom part by rounding a different corner. You'll need to add the markup to each menu element tough, and play with the display property. You could try to reduce as much as possible by using the ::before and/or ::after elements but I doupt you'd be able to save much (just maybe get to replace the inner div maybe?)